# Remove undesired characters with REGEX

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some text like that:

> some words  some more words

I tried that:

```
$line=preg_replace('#[^\x00-\x7f]+#','',$line)
```

But it doesn't work. The code of one of the characters seems to be 61558 if it can help.

Thanks

Comment: Works here, https://eval.in/521879. Is that your actual string?

Comment: After reading your comment I find the solution, it was an utf8 issue, I added "u" option and it worked. Thanks